# A question on enlarging the "/boot" space with the "GParted"

Tags: boot, partitioning, gparted

When I try to update, I see

```
Not enough free disk space on `/boot`
```

I know I can use `sudo apt-get autoremove`, but there are only two versions `4.4.0-45` and the current one `4.4.0-47` as you can see in picture one:

[image: picture 1]

So I decided to enlarge `/boot` space with *GParted*.

However, I can't resize `/dev/sda11` where `/boot` is. I think it is the small "key" following `/dev/sda11` as you can see in picture two:

[image: picture 2]

What should I do to solve the problem?

If it matters, it is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Maybe I need to boot from ubuntu Live CD...

Comment: The key is only telling you that _GRUB_ is there, and yes a _live cd_ is what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your partition table is pretty cramped for space. You would have to do a reinstall with lvm for flexibility to be able to enlarge partitions as you see fit.

What I would do is just 'sudo apt-get autoremove' to uninstall your old, unused kernels. That will remove them from the /boot directory and free some space.

Comment: Thank you very much  at first!  I solved  it by put free space following the "/boot"other than preceding ,and it works.

Comment: There is also a "Windows 10 " on my hard disk so that my partition table is pretty cramped for space.